# Validate ip and hostname laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how I can validate ip and hostname on unique?
In database I have column ip, and there stored all ips and hostnames. How I can check if ip exists in database?

I know, that for validation I need use:

```
$ip = request()->ip;
if(gethostbyname($ip) == $database->column-ip || $ip == $database->column-ip)
  return false;
}
```

But how validate in laravel? I know that I can with unique rule do this, but how gethostname then?

```
['data.ip' => 'required|unique:ips_table,ip']
```

have ideas how to do this?

Comment: you have hostname also stored in your database?

Comment: nope, I get hostname with function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [make your own validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules), e.g. `uniqueip`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are looking to make the IP unique per hostname? If that's the case, you can add a clause to your unique validation rule (assuming your host_name_column is in your `ips_table`) :

```
['data.ip' => 'required|unique:ips_table,ip,NULL,id,host_name_column,'.$host_name_value]
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique for more info.